# In Java, convert the dot to comma in DecimalFormat replace method

Tags: java, replace, android-edittext, decimalformat

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if( editText != null)
        {
            if(editText.getText().length() > 0){
                    String TL = null;
                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
                    String ss = "";
                    try{
                        ss = editText.getText().toString();
                        ss = ss.replace(".", "");
                        ss = ss.replace(",", "");
                        Long number = Long.parseLong(ss);
                        ss = formatter.format(number);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        ss = e.toString();
                    }
                    changeText(editText,ss);
                }

            editText.setSelection(editText.length());
            }

    }
```

when the user enter the value like 50000 answer is 50.000 in editText. But,
I dont want to dot. I want to comma like 50,000. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
formatter.setDecimalSeparator('.');
formatter.setGroupingSeparator(',');
```

Or more dangerous, as global

```
Locale.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
```